# Picard group of a Torus

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, kahler-manifolds

I want to calculate the Picard group of a Torus. For simplicity, a Torus of complex dimension 1: $X=\mathbb C/\Lambda$ So far, I looked at the exponential sequence

$$\to H^1(X,\mathbb Z) \to H^1(X,O_X) \to H^1(X,O^*_X) \to H^2(X,\mathbb Z) \to H^2(X,O_X) \to $$

and got the following:

$$\to \mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb C \to \text{Pic}(X) \to \mathbb Z \to 0.$$

The first map is injective, as it is induced by the inclusion $\mathbb Z \subset O_X$.

Furthermore, under the isomorphism $H^1(X,O_X) = H^{0,1}(X)$, the first map should be given by $(1,1)\mapsto (1,\tau)$, where $\Lambda =\mathbb Z + \tau \mathbb Z$.

But how do I proceed from here? How can I figure out the other maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you have, you see that there is a short exact sequence of abelian groups $0\to\mathbb C/\Lambda\to Pic\to\mathbb Z\to 0$ and since $\mathbb Z$ is a free abelian group that sequence splits, so that $Pic$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C/\Lambda\oplus \mathbb Z$. In terms fo this isomorphism, the maps in the sequence are the obvious ones.

Comment: Ah, I see. Its easier than I thought. With obvious ones, do you mean with respect to the splitting, so inclusion and projection? How can I picture the isomorphism from the picard group?

Comment: The inclusion makes no sense, as there is no $\mathbb C$ inside $Pic$… but there is a quotient map into the first summand: that's the obvious map.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "picture the isomorphism from the Picard group"? Unless you pick some *other* description of the Picard group, you simply cannot do that.

Comment: (If you want to use the description of Pic in terms of divisors, that is precisely what the reference given by Arnaud does…)

Comment: I meant the inclusion of $\mathbb C/\Lambda$ in $Pic$, so i guess we agree. Regarding "picture the isomorphism", I was just wondering, why the base space appears. I will take a look at the reference.

Comment: The $X$ in $Pic$ comes from the divisors of degree $0$ (since the map $Pic\to\mathbb Z$ is precisely the degree) If you fix a point $p\in X$, then for each other point $q$ there is a degree zero divisor $q-p$ on $X$, and that determines an element of that kernel.The point is that this is an isomorphism.